# How to Store Image in a Directory File & Keeping Path in Database

Tags: mysql, vb.net

I'm trying to create a program that retrieve image in directory folder that when i select records in datagridview the records display & the image restore in the directory folder will also display in the form.

Comment: It might be useful if you tell us how far you've got already, or what specific code problem you have?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take a moment to read this *carefully*: [Ask]